# Ctrl + Enter not working in laravel-web-tinker Package

Tags: php, laravel, tinker

I am using the laravel-web-tinker package ob Ubuntu PHP 7.4 but When I press Ctrl + Enter, It is not working, php artisan serve shows "Killed" and stops working.
OS: Ubuntu 20.10
Laravel: 6
PHP: 7.4.3

Comment: Have you seen that issue on GitHub? https://github.com/spatie/laravel-web-tinker/issues/15